# profile and zprofile not both executed for login shellss?

Tags: macos, shell, zsh

When I open a shell, **.zprofile** is automatically sourced but **.profile** not. I verify this because

**.zprofile** contains

```
echo "we are in zprofile"
...
```

**.profile** contains

```
echo "we are in profile"
...
```

and when opening a new shell I get only

```
we are in zprofile
```

which seems to be in contradiction with [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/388622/zsh-zprofile-zshrc-zlogin-what-goes-where) which says that **.zprofile** is sourced for login shells only.

so should both be not be sourced when opening a "normal" shell?

Also when I do `su - johnsmith` or `su johnsmith --login`, the .profile is not beeing sourced and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zsh ignores `.profile`. That file is not mentioned in the Zsh docs or the post you linked.

If you want to use `.profile` in `.zprofile`, you must manually source `.profile`.

Ideally you would also run it in `emulate sh` mode because Zsh is not a strict superset of Posix Sh. You can use an anonymous function for this:

```
if [[ -f ~/.profile ]]; then
  function {
    emulate -L sh
    source ~/.profile
  }
fi
```

If your `.zprofile` is running on every new shell (not just on first login), then you must be starting new *login* shells. This is atypical and arguably incorrect on Linux, but it is the default and expected behavior on MacOS.

Comment: So if I open just a shell by clicking on the icon, is it a login-shell or a non-login shell?

Comment: @roi_saumon this question is tagged with "macos" so I assume you are using MacOS. If "the icon" means Terminal.app, then yes: by default, that will and should start a login shell.

Comment: okay, out of curiosity how do you open a non login shell?

Comment: @roi_saumon If you are already in a shell session and you invoke `zsh` without any options, that should be a non-login shell. The "login shell" is meant to run one-time setup that will be inherited by any non-login shells that you open later. In general on MacOS, you should allow your terminal to open a login shell by default. Note that on Linux and BSD, it's conventional to set up your user session some other way (e.g. by sourcing `~/.profile` from an X11 configuration script) and so terminals on Linux and BSD tend *not* to start login shells, and generally are expected not to.

Comment: My problem with `emulate` is that it's very slow.

Comment: @shadowtalker If you change the default shell to `bash` you will come to the realization that it's not a login shell at all, since it won't source `.bash_profile`. It seems Apple implemented a quirk so much so that `.zprofile` is sourced when you open a new Terminal window, causing the Terminal itself acting like it is a login shell when its not.

Comment: @MartinBraun where is that implemented? I'm not familiar with it on any Mac I've had, and I don't see it in `/etc/zshenv` or `/etc/zshrc*` or in the Terminal.app defaults. Is that a feature of newer MacOS versions than Monterey? I'm pretty sure it at least used to be the case that Terminal.app opened a login shell by default, and it was visible from e.g. `[[ -o login ]]`.

Comment: I also have never noticed a performance problem with `emulate`. I call it several times throughout my Zsh config, and the primary bottleneck there is just file I/O due to sourcing several scripts (as of when I last measured, which was a while ago).

Comment: @shadowtalker I gathered more information, I was wrong. Apple's terminals spawn login shells, whereas Linux terminals spawn normal shells. So changing the default shell to `bash` using `chsh` the terminal itself will still be a login shell. It will source `.bash_profile`. My wrong assumption was a result of having `zsh` spawning a `bash` shell which consequently would not source `.bash_profile`.

Comment: @shadowtalker In regards of `emulate`, it is noticeably slower, but we are still talking about fractions of a second. I think part of the problem is that emulate itself will spawn a subshell to properly emulate? I'm not sure about that, but after improving my configuration, the drag is minimal.